Norm equality problem concerning the numerical radius
can someone help me to prove the following equality.
$$\sup _{\theta \in R}||\Re(e^{i\theta}A)||=w(A)$$
Where $w(A)=\sup _{||x||=1}\vert\langle Ax,x\rangle\vert$, Where A is a bounded operator.

We will use two properties: $\langle u,v\rangle \ge 0$ implies $\langle v,u\rangle =\langle u,v\rangle$ and $w(T)=\|T\|$ for any selfadjoint operator $T.$
For $\|x\|=1$ there is $\theta_x$ such that $$|\langle Ax,x\rangle|=e^{i\theta_x}\langle Ax,x\rangle=\langle e^{i\theta_x} Ax,x\rangle\\ =\langle x,e^{i\theta_x} Ax\rangle=\langle e^{-i\theta_x} A^*x,x\rangle=\langle \Re(e^{i\theta_x}A)x,x\rangle\\ \le \|\Re(e^{i\theta_x}A)\|
\le \sup_\theta \|\Re(e^{i\theta}A)\|$$
Hence $w(A)\le \sup_\theta \|\Re(e^{i\theta}A)\|.$
On the other hand $$\|\Re(e^{i\theta}A)\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}|\langle \Re(e^{i\theta}A)x,x\rangle |\le \sup_{\|x\|=1}|\langle Ax,x\rangle|=w(A)$$ Thus $ \sup_\theta \|\Re(e^{i\theta}A)\|\le w(A).$

First, thank you so much for your answer, I would like to clarify some things further if possible.
In the first set of equalities, $\langle e^{i\theta _{x}}Ax,x\rangle =\langle \Re (e^{i\theta _{x}}A)x,x\rangle$, why? the left hand side is positive, how do we know that $\Re (e^{i\theta _{x}}A) $is positive?
Also, you used $||\Re (e^{i\theta _{x}}A)||=\sup _{||x||=1}| |\langle \Re e^{i\theta _{x}}Ax,x\rangle |$ and this holds for selfadjoint operators I believe, that is |\Re e^{i\theta _{x}}A| is selfadjoint?

I mistakenly wrote $\Re (e^{i\theta _{x}}A)$, I meant why is $\langle \Re (e^{i\theta _{x}}A)x,x\rangle$ positive, also in the end is $\Re (e^{i\theta _{x}}A)$, why is it self adjoint?

I have taken for granted that $\Re(T)={1\over 2}(T+T^*).$ Is this correct ?

That explains why $\Re (T)$ is selfadjoint, but why is $e^{-i\theta _{x}}A^{*}=\Re (e^{i\theta _{x}}A)$?
What is $\Re (e^{i\theta _{x}}x)$ equal to? I guess I cant just apply the formula for $\Re(T)$ since in that case we get a real part of an operator, and in our case we have a complex multiple.

Sorry for asking a lot, I just want to understand this..

I think that I got it now, can you please verify this.
$$\Re (e^{i\theta}A)=\frac{e^{i\theta}A+(e^{i\theta}A)^{}}{2}$$
From here we have like in the first line, $$\langle e^{i\theta}Ax,x\rangle = \langle x,e^{i\theta}A\rangle = \langle e^{-i\theta}A^{}x,x\rangle$$ from which we get that $$\Re (e^{i\theta}A)=\frac{1}{2}\langle e^{-i\theta}A^{}x,x\rangle +\frac{1}{2}\langle e^{-i\theta}A^{}x,x\rangle$$

Should be $$\Re (e^{i\theta}A)={1\over 2}\langle e^{i\theta} Ax,x\rangle +{1\over 2}\langle e^{-i\theta}A^*x,x\rangle=\langle e^{i\theta }Ax,x\rangle$$

Yes, but using your first equalities, $$|\langle Ax,x\rangle |=e^{i\theta}\langle Ax,x\rangle =\langle x,e^{i\theta}Ax\rangle = \langle e^{-i\theta}A^{}x,x\rangle$$, is this how $$\frac{1}{2}\langle e^{i\theta}Ax,x\rangle +\frac{1}{2}\langle e^{-i\theta}A^{}x,x\rangle = \langle e^{i\theta}Ax,x\rangle $$ ?

Sorry for bothering you, I just want to clear this out, thank you so much!

Yes, your previous comment is fine.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Let me just clarify one more thing, since $$\langle e^{i\theta}Ax,x\rangle =\langle e^{-i\theta}A^{}x,x\rangle $$ based on the first equalities and since
$$\langle \Re(e^{i\theta}A)x,x\rangle =\frac{1}{2}\langle e^{i\theta}Ax,x\rangle +\frac{1}{2}\langle e^{-i\theta}A^{}x,x\rangle$$, it follows that $$\Re(e^{i\theta}A)=\langle e^{i\theta}Ax,x\rangle = \langle e^{-i\theta}A^{*}x,x\rangle$$ I guess this follows logically, just to confirm.
